# Multiple developers on a Titanium project

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator

I'm making an iPhone app with Appcelerator Titanium and I want to share the source code
 with a few more programmers. I will use a SCM repository which at some point might be open to the general public.

Now my question is, are there any files which I should *not* commit to the repository?

- In project root I can tell that tiapp.xml and mainfest are telling the app GUID, is there any reason for me to keep that private? (this value is also shown many places in the build/ folder)
- I've added everything in the Resources/ folder.
- If I skip the build/iphone/build/ folder, will developers still be able to build the project?

Side question - When another programmer downloads this code, it seems to me that (s)he has to have the same directory structure as I do? Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the project with two developers. What I did was put in to solve .gitignore the build folder and compile each developer on your machine, generating the same.

Comment: You can check in everything except the /build/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

As my experience, at first, I create a new blank project, commit all to SVN. After that, I try to add a few codes, rebuild and see which files is red (means it changes content) except the file I modify. These red files maybe need to removed.